# How to use torch.nn.transformer with pytroch lightning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to use the vanilla transformer from PyTorch using Pytorch Lightning. I tried to test the model with a reverse number task. So given [1, 3, 5, 4, 13, 19] it returns [1, 13, 4, 5, 3, 19] with 1, 19 being start and end token respectively. The full code is below. The code can run without error but there seems to be a problem with the backpropagation. The training loss does go down at first but it doesn't go beyond 2.8 and the accuracy doesn't go beyond 11%.

It seems that part of the model is able to optimize, I am guessing it is because the weights located in `Embeddings` and `Generator` can backpropagate, but weights located in `nn.Transformer` cannot? I am really not sure.

```
import math
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import EarlyStopping


class Embeddings(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, d_model, vocab):
        super(Embeddings, self).__init__()
        self.lut = nn.Embedding(vocab, d_model)
        self.d_model = d_model

    def forward(self, x):
        a = self.lut(x) * math.sqrt(self.d_model)
        return a


class PositionalEncoding(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, d_model, dropout, max_len=5000):
        super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)

        # Compute the positional encodings once in log space.
        pe = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model)
        position = torch.arange(0, max_len).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2) *
                             -(math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        pe = pe.unsqueeze(0)
        self.register_buffer('pe', pe)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x + self.pe[:, :x.size(1)]
        return self.dropout(x)


class Generator(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, size):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.proj = nn.Linear(512, size)
    def forward(self, x):
        return F.log_softmax(self.proj(x), dim=-1)


class Model(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, src_embed, tgt_embed, transformer, generator):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.src_embed = src_embed
        self.tgt_embed = tgt_embed
        self.transformer = transformer
        self.generator = generator
        self.valLoss = 0
        self.valAcc = 0
        self.automatic_optimization = False
        self.optimizer = None
        for p in self.parameters():
            if p.dim() > 1:
                nn.init.xavier_uniform_(p)

    def forward(self, x, y, tgt_mask=None):
        x = self.src_embed(x)
        y = self.tgt_embed(y)
        return self.generator(self.transformer(x, y, tgt_mask=tgt_mask))
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        if self.optimizer is None:
            self.optimizer = self.optimizers()
        batch = Batch(batch[0], batch[1])
        tgt_mask = batch.trg_mask.squeeze(0)
        tgt_mask = (tgt_mask != True)
        output = self(batch.src, batch.trg, tgt_mask)
        criterion = LossCompute(V)
        loss = criterion.forward(output.contiguous().view(-1, output.size(-1)), batch.trg_y.contiguous().view(-1)) / batch.ntokens
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        self.log('train_loss', loss)
        print(loss)

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        batch = Batch(batch[0], batch[1])
        tgt_mask = batch.trg_mask.squeeze(0)
        tgt_mask = (tgt_mask != True)
        output = self(batch.src, batch.trg, tgt_mask)
        criterion = LossCompute(V)
        loss = criterion.forward(output.view(-1, output.size(-1)), batch.trg_y.contiguous().view(-1)) / batch.ntokens
        self.log('val_loss', loss)
        self.valLoss += loss
        if batch_idx % 10 == 0:
            print(loss)
        if batch_idx == 99:
            print(self.valLoss/100)
            self.valLoss = 0
        return {"x": output, "trg": batch.trg_y, "index": batch_idx}
    def validation_step_end(self, batch):
        output, trg, idx = batch["x"], batch["trg"], batch["index"]
        accuracy = getAccuracy(output, trg)
        self.log("accuracy", accuracy)
        self.valAcc += accuracy
        if idx == 99:
            print(self.valAcc/100)
            self.valAcc = 0

    def train_dataloader(self):
        data = data_gen(V, 0, 3000)
        return DataLoader(data, batch_size=30, shuffle=False, num_workers=2, pin_memory=True)

    def val_dataloader(self):
        data = data_gen(V, 1, 1000)
        return DataLoader(data, batch_size=10, shuffle=False, num_workers=2, pin_memory=True)
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=1e-3, betas=(0.9, 0.98), eps=1e-9)



class LossCompute(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, size):
        super(LossCompute, self).__init__()
        self.criterion = nn.KLDivLoss(reduction='sum')
        self.size = size
        self.true_dist = None

    def forward(self, x, target):
        # x has size (batch_size x length, vocab_size)
        assert x.size(1) == self.size
        true_dist = x.data.clone()
        true_dist.fill_(0)
        true_dist.scatter_(1, target.data.unsqueeze(1).long(), 1)
        self.true_dist = true_dist
        return self.criterion(x, true_dist)

# prepare data
class Batch:
    "Object for holding a batch of data with mask during training."
    def __init__(self, src, trg=None):
        self.src = src
        if trg is not None:
            self.trg = trg[:, :-1]
            self.trg_y = trg[:, 1:]
            self.trg_mask = \
                self.make_std_mask(self.trg)
            self.ntokens = self.trg_y.size(0) * self.trg_y.size(1)
            print("")

    @staticmethod
    def make_std_mask(tgt):
        "Create a mask to hide padding and future words."
        tgt_mask = subsequent_mask(tgt.size(-1)).type_as(tgt.data)
        return tgt_mask

def subsequent_mask(size):
    "Mask out subsequent positions."
    attn_shape = (1, size, size)
    subsequent_mask = np.triu(np.ones(attn_shape), k=1).astype('uint8')
    return torch.from_numpy(subsequent_mask) == 0


def data_gen(V, randomSeed, totalTrainingSample):
    np.random.seed(randomSeed)
    x = torch.from_numpy(np.random.randint(2, V - 2, size=(totalTrainingSample, 10)))
    y = torch.flip(torch.flip(x, [0, 1]), [0])
    x[:, 0] = 1
    y[:, 0] = 1
    x[:, -1] = V - 1
    y[:, -1] = V - 1
    return list(zip(x, y))


def getAccuracy(x, trg):
    totalValAcc = 0
    totalValAccToken = 0
    trg = trg.contiguous().view(-1)
    out = x.view(-1, x.size(-1))  # (batch_size * tgt_length, src_vocab)
    _, index = torch.max(out, dim=-1)  # index (batch_size * tgt_length)
    correct = list((trg == index)).count(True)
    totalValAcc += correct
    totalValAccToken += index.size(0)
    return totalValAcc / totalValAccToken

V = 20
transformer = nn.Transformer(num_encoder_layers=2, num_decoder_layers=2, batch_first=True)
PositionEnc = PositionalEncoding(512, 0.1)
src_emb = Embeddings(512, V)
tgt_emb = Embeddings(512, V)
gen = Generator(V)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = Model(nn.Sequential(src_emb, PositionEnc), nn.Sequential(tgt_emb, PositionEnc), transformer, gen)
    earlyStopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)
    trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=10, callbacks=[earlyStopping])
    trainer.fit(model)
```